# Callback after Rails link with data-remote="true" and data-method="PUT"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, callback, link-to, link-to-remote

I have this ruby code:

```
link_to t("general.actions.#{ action }"), [action, @app, item], { 
   :method => :put, 
   :remote => true, 
   :onclick => '$(this).closest("tr").find("td").fadeOut()' 
}, :class => 'status'
```

which generates this html:

```
<a href="/apps/guess-the-model/contents/52118140d644363dc4000005/approve" 
   data-method="put" 
   data-remote="true" 
   onclick="$(this).closest("tr").find("td").fadeOut()" 
   rel="nofollow">
    approve
</a>
```

The problem is, i shouldn't use onclick. I should call this js code only if the AJAX is successfull, so I should somehow pass a callback and check XMLHttpRequest status. How can I do that using `:remote => true` and `:method= :put`?

Comment: I think, you should write this js in the method's js template, which is being called by the remote link.

Answer (score 4):

With `remote: true`, Rails makes an ajax call to your controller action with format `js`.  So, in your controller's action when you're ready to render the output you just need to specify `format.js` option as follows:

```
def action
  ...

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {...} # You probably have something like this already
    format.js {} # Add this line
end
```

Then, you need add a `action.js.erb` file in your `app/views/app/` directory and execute the javascript code that you wanted to execute on `onclick` there.

Answer (score 0):

You could also [use the 'ajax:success' hook](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#link-to) in your javascript like so:

**jQuery**

```
$('a.status').on('ajax:success', function(ev) {
    $(this).closest("tr").find("td").fadeOut()
})
```

**Coffee**

```
$ ->
    $("a.status").on "ajax:success", (event) ->
    //your code
```

And remove the `onclick` attribute of your link.